# how to merge cells with same value in one row

Tags: excel, vba

How do I merge cells with the same value and color in a row?

[image]

and the result should be :

[image]

Comment: Is this in the same worksheet? What are the addresses of the cells?

Comment: Probably a VBA loop going from bottom to top and deleting the current row when it matches the one above it.  Sort seems out of the question, and SQL Distinct would also collapse the second instance of key values 1/ochre.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could try this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim LastRow As Long, i As Long, Value As Long
    Dim Color As Double

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        For i = LastRow To 2 Step -1

            Value = .Range("A" & i).Value
            Color = .Range("A" & i).Interior.Color

            If .Range("A" & i - 1).Value = Value And .Range("A" & i - 1).Interior.Color = Color Then
                .Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
            End If

        Next i

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: thank you so much. I had to change the value into string since I have the cells in words.

Comment: @Yahyaotaif glad to help!

Comment: @Errir 1004 So if I needed to apply this to e.g. columns from A to H, what would be the range like ?

Answer (score 1):

## Copy Consecutive to One

- Adjust the values in the constants section to fit your needs.
- The image looks like you want all this to happen in the same column
  of the same worksheet, which is adjusted in the constants section.
- Before writing to Target Column (`cTgtCol`), the code will clear its
  contents. Be careful not to lose data.
- Colors are applied using a loop, which will slow down the fast array approach of copying the data.

### The Code

```
Sub CopyConsecutiveToOne()

    ' Source
    Const cSource As Variant = "Sheet1"   ' Worksheet Name/Index
    Const cSrcCol As Variant = "A"        ' Column Letter/Number
    Const cSrcFR As Long = 1              ' Column First Row Number
    ' Target
    Const cTarget As Variant = "Sheet1"   ' Worksheet Name/Index
    Const cTgtCol As Variant = "A"        ' Column Letter/Number
    Const cTgtFR As Long = 1              ' Column First Row Number

    Dim rng As Range      ' Source Column Last Used Cell Range,
                          ' Source Column Range, Target Column Range
    Dim vntS As Variant   ' Source Array
    Dim vntT As Variant   ' Target Array
    Dim vntC As Variant   ' Color Array
    Dim i As Long         ' Source Range/Array Row/Element Counter
    Dim k As Long         ' Target/Color Array Element Counter

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    End With
    'On Error GoTo ProcedureExit

    ' In Source Worksheet
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(cSource).Columns(cSrcCol)
        ' Calculate Source Column Last Used Cell Range.
        Set rng = .Find("*", , xlFormulas, xlWhole, xlByColumns, xlPrevious)
        ' Check if data in Source Column.
        If Not rng Is Nothing Then  ' Data found.
            ' Calculate Source Range.
            Set rng = .Range(.Cells(cSrcFR), .Cells(rng.Row))
            ' Copy values from Source Range to Source Array.
            vntS = rng
          Else                      ' Data Not Found.
            With .Cells(1)
                MsgBox "No Data in column '" & .Split(.Address, "$")(1) & "'."
                GoTo ProcedureExit
            End With
        End If
    End With

    ' In Arrays
    ' Count the number of elements in Target/Color Array.
    k = 1 ' The first element will be included before the loop.
    ' Loop through elements of Source Array.
    For i = 2 To UBound(vntS)
        ' Check if current value is different then the previous one.
        If vntS(i, 1) <> vntS(i - 1, 1) Then
            ' Count element of Target/Color Array.
            k = k + 1
        End If
    Next

    ' Write to Target/Color Arrays
    ' Resize Target/Color Arrays.
    ReDim vntT(1 To k, 1 To 1)
    ReDim vntC(1 To k, 1 To 1)
    ' Reset Counter
    k = 1 ' The first element will be included before the loop.
    ' Write first value from Source Array to Target Array.
    vntT(1, 1) = vntS(1, 1)
    ' Write first color value to Target Color Array.
    vntC(1, 1) = rng.Cells(1, 1).Interior.Color
    ' Loop through elements of Source Array.
    For i = 2 To UBound(vntS)
        ' Check if current value is different then the previous one.
        If vntS(i, 1) <> vntS(i - 1, 1) Then
            ' Count element of Target/Color Array.
            k = k + 1
            ' Write from Source Array to Target Array.
            vntT(k, 1) = vntS(i, 1)
            ' Write color values from Source Range to Color Array.
            vntC(k, 1) = rng.Cells(i, 1).Interior.Color
        End If
    Next

    ' All necessary data is in Target/Color Arrays.
    Erase vntS
    Set rng = Nothing

    ' In Target Worksheet
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(cTarget).Cells(cTgtFR, cTgtCol)
        ' Clear contents of range from Target First Cell to Target Bottom Cell.
        .Resize(Rows.Count - .Row + 1).ClearContents
        ' Calculate Target Column Range.
        Set rng = .Resize(k)
        ' Copy Target Array to Target Range.
        rng = vntT
        ' Apply colors to Target Range.
        With rng
            ' Loop through cells of Target Column Range.
            For i = 1 To k
                ' Apply color to current cell of Target Range using the values
                ' from Color Array.
                .Cells(i, 1).Interior.Color = vntC(i, 1)
            Next
        End With
    End With


ProcedureExit:
    With Application
        .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: thank you for the code. Your code seems complex for the problem. All I needed is to loop through the cells and if the current value matches the one below, then delete the current value and set the value to be the new cell.

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom function in Visual Basic Editor that will return to the color index of the cell:

```
Function COLOR(Target As Range)
    COLOR = Target.Interior.ColorIndex
End Function
```

Then in the right column use a formula similar to this:

```
=IF(OR(A2<>A3,COLOR(A2)<>COLOR(A3)),1,0)
```

[image: You will get something like this.]

Then filter to show only 1's.

Comment: Yusuf Cakmak good thinking. However, the idea is to compare two values, if they are the same then delete one.